# Displaying from Smarty array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, smarty

I've Following type of array in smarty..

```
[Main_array] => Array
(
    [splitlist] => 1
    [counter] => 2
    [listNames] => Array
        (
            [0] => Material
            [1] => Color
        )

    [splittedLists] => Array
        (
            [Material_item_1] => Array
                (
                    [White] => Array
                        ( 
                            [image] => /img/thumbnail.gif
                            [imageLink] => /static/white.html
                        )

                    [Black] => Array
                        (

                            [image] => /img/no-image.gif
                            [imageLink] => /static/black.html
                        )
                )

            [Material_item_2] => Array
                (
                    [Red] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => /img/no-image.gif
                            [imageLink] => /static/Red.html
                        )

                    [Yellow] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => /img/no-image.gif
                            [imageLink] => /static/yellow.html
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

I want following output from this array

```
*  Material
    -  Material_item_1
    -  Material_item_2
*  Color
    -  Nude
    -  Black
    -  Red
    -  Yellow
```

And what i've done so far is as follow..

```
[{foreach from=$item2.listNames key=subKey1 item=subItem1 name=subLp1}]
   <h2>
       <label>[{$subItem1|replace:"-":" "}]</label>
   </h2>
   <ul style="margin-left:20px;display:block;">
      [{foreach from=$item2.splittedLists key=subKey2 item=subItem2 name=subLp2}]
         <li style="float:none;"><strong>[{$subKey2|replace:"-":" "}]</strong></li>
      [{/foreach}]
   </ul>
[{/foreach}]
```

And I'm getting....

```
*  Material
    -   Material_item_1
    -   Material_item_1
    -   Material_item_2
    -   Material_item_2
*  Color
    -   Material_item_1
    -   Material_item_1
    -   Material_item_2
    -   Material_item_2
```

I'm using PHP - OXID & Smarty. One thing I should mention here is the element of `[splittedLists]` could be more than or less than 2. But logic for 2 element is also welcome.

**UPDATE:** I've talked to client and So, Now any suggestion regarding changes in structure are also welcome. Plz help

**UPDATE2:** Here follows the PHP array.

```
$arr = array(
    'Main_array' => array
    (
        'splitlist' => 1,
        'counter' => 2,
        'listNames' => array
        (
            '0' => "Material",
            '1' => "Color"
        ),
        'splittedLists' => array
        (
            'Material_item_1' => array
            (
                'White' => array
                ( 
                   'image' => "/img/thumbnail.gif",
                   'imageLink' => "/static/white.html"
                ),
                'Black' => array
                (
                   'image' => "/img/no-image.gif",
                   'imageLink' => "/static/black.html"
                 )
            ),

            'Material_item_2' => array
                (
                    'Red' => array
                        (
                            'image' => "/img/no-image.gif",
                            'imageLink' => "/static/Red.html"
                        ),

                    'Yellow' => array
                        (
                            'image' => "/img/no-image.gif",
                            'imageLink' => "/static/yellow.html"
                        )
                )
        )
)
);
```

Comment: can you show the array,instead of var_dump?

Comment: @Sibu This array i put here usign `print_r` function and I think its enough.

Comment: i wanted to execute your code, so if can provide array..maybe i will try

Comment: i want the full array output.. so that i can help :)

Comment: @Sibu & Vijay:  PHP array is added to... Hope this will useful to answer my question.. Thanks Buddies..

Comment: @VijayJoseph Have a look frnd..

Comment: I don't think you posted the correct array. I'm getting different array output than you got. It does not have the elements like  Python-Leather, Leather. Please post the right array or let me know the exact output you want with the array $arr

Comment: @VijayJoseph Hey, Thanks... I've corrected the output.. now please have a look at it..

Comment: I'm a little confused on the array. It has 2 material items, each with its own set of colors. But the output you want lists the materials and colors separately. Shouldn't each set of colors be listed under its own material? Or is the output intended the way it is?

Answer (score 1):

For array you presented in PHP in Smarty 3.1.18 it should look like this:

```
{foreach $item2.listNames as $listType}
   <h2>
       <label>{$listType}</label>
   </h2>

   <ul style="margin-left:20px;display:block;">

      {if $listType eq 'Material'}
                {foreach $item2.splittedLists as $k => $v}
                    <li style="float:none;"><strong>{$k}</strong></li>
                {/foreach}
      {elseif $listType eq 'Color'}
               {foreach $item2.splittedLists as $k => $v}
                  {foreach $v as $colour => $versions}
                    <li style="float:none;"><strong>{$colour}</strong></li>
                  {/foreach}
               {/foreach}
      {/if}
   </ul>   
{/foreach}
```

Output for this will be:

```
 Material

    Material_item_1
    Material_item_2

Color

    White
    Black
    Red
    Yellow
```

(Of course no "Nude" is displayed because it wasn't in array)